# Why using explicit interpreter in bash doesn't use path variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Say I have a script /tmp/printy.py containing only:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
print "hello world"
```

Why does this work:

```
chmod +x /tmp/printy.py
export PATH=$PATH:/tmp/
printy.py
```

But this doesn't:

```
chmod +x /tmp/printy.py
export PATH=$PATH:/tmp/
python printy.py
```

And what can be added to, say, a cron job which is supposed to run printy.py with a specific interpreter, to make it work?

Quite possibly duplicate but I can't find anything, maybe I'm using the wrong search terms?

Comment: Just use the whole path `python /tmp/printy.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path lookups in the shell only apply to *commands*, not arbitrary files. In your first example, `printy.py` is the command name. In the second, it is just an argument to Python, and Python doesn't use `PATH` to find the script to run; it expects `printy.py` to be in the current working directory.

You can use a combination of `PYTHONPATH` and `-m` to simulate this:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PATH python -m printy
```

Comment: This is a good explanation of why but is there a way of overriding the hashbang? For example running printy.py from outside the directory it is in, with something other than the specified interpreter?

Comment: Path lookups could apply to arbitrary files, it all depends on the calling application. All that happens is the string `printy.py` is passed to python, it can choose whatever it wants to do with that information.

Comment: FWIW I tried similar with Perl and same thing happens. I know python *could* be made to do this using sys.path trickery.

Comment: @jambox The hashbang is ignored completely unless you run the program as an exectuable, i.e no calling program.

Comment: @jambox : But Perl can be told to use PATH for searching the program, and Python doesn't.

Comment: @user1934428 do you mean with -S? I just found it in the man page.

Comment: You can also use `which` to search the PATH for the script, as in `python "$(which printy.py)"`. But this will fail with weird error messages if printy.py is not found in the PATH.

Comment: @GordonDavisson That only works if the file is executable, you can use `type -p file` for all files.